# Finding a flaw in a proof that $(A\cup C)\times (B \cup D)\subseteq(A\times B)\cup(C\times D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

[image]

> The only problem I could see is that there should be two more cases: $x \in A$ and $y \in D$; and $x \in C$ and $y \in B$. Please suggest.

Comment: Yes, that's the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, what you said is the error. The correct statement would be $$(A\cup C)\times(B\cup D)\subset(A\times B)\cup (A\times D)\cup (C\times B)\cup (C\times D)$$